# Qual é a diferença entre inicializar um construtor ou fazer atribuição dentro do construtor?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor, inicialização

Qual a diferença entre os dois exemplos abaixo?

Devo fazer também atribuição do valor dentro do construtor nesta classe mesmo tendo inicializado?

exemplo 1:

```
class sof{
   int teste;
public: 
   sof(int t) : teste(t){}
);
```

exemplo 2:

```
class sof{
   int teste;
public: 
   sof(int t){
    teste = t;
   }
);
```

Comment: Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse é exemplo é indiferente já que `int` não tem um construtor padrão. A construção é feita diretamente pelo compilador na atribuição. Seria diferente se o tipo do membro a ser inicializado fosse um tipo que possui um construtor padrão.

Vamos pensar em algo assim:

```
class Tipo {
    int x;
public:
    Tipo() {
        x = 0;
    }
    Tipo(int p) {
        x = p;
    }
}

class sof {
    Tipo teste; //chama o construtor padrão
public: 
    sof(int t) {
        teste = Tipo(t); //chama o outro construtor
    }
};

class sof {
    Tipo teste; //não chama nada
public: 
    sof(Tipo t) : teste(t) {} //chama o construtor com parâmetro
};
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o7VHUH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gokmmqrw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/ConstrutorInit.cpp).

Note que se não existir o construtor padrão, não tem opção, a forma de inicialização de membro por lista (esta última) é exigida.

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

[FAQ oficial](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#overview-ctors).

Comment: Relativamente os inicializadores são independentes do que é feito dentro do constructor? Imagine que tenho de fazer algumas verificações dentro do constructor, não devo colocar inicializadores?

Comment: Bom, isso é outra perguntas, mas não seria isso necessariamente. Você pode fazer, mas aí cai no caso de chamar o construtor padrão, se for isto que deseja, ok. Se prefere inicializar da forma desejada e depois fazer algo novamente dentro do construtor é com você. Em grande parte dos casos poderá escolher um ou outro. Tem casos que você não tem a opção de deixar a chamada do construtor padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de completar a resposta anterior com o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>

class Tipo {
    int x;
public:
    Tipo() {
        x = 0;
        std::cout << "tipo-default\n";
    }
    Tipo(int p) {
        x = p;
        std::cout << "tipo-int\n";
    }
};

class sof {
    std::ostream& x;
    Tipo teste;
public:
    sof(int t) : x(std::cout << "sof\n") {
        std::cout << "sof-constr\n";
        teste = Tipo(t);
    }
};

int main() {
    sof s(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Aqui mostro o caso citado pela resposta anterior e, além disso, mostro que o construtor de `sof` não é chamado na execução do escopo da classe, porém logo antes desse construtor ser chamado, como é mostrado no output:

```
sof
tipo-default
sof-constr
tipo-int
```

Mas também é possível ver o outro caso da utilidade do *member initializer lists* que é o caso do `std::ostream& x`: este deve ser declarado e inicializado no "mesmo statement" por ser referência (um outro caso seria variáveis do tipo `const`), logo não pode ser inicializado no escopo do construtor de `sof`.