# C++: Elementos logo abaixo da chamada do construtor de uma classe

Tags: c++, classes, template, construtor

No código de meu professor, ele passou a seguinte template classe, com o construtor definido abaixo:

```
template<typename T>
class CircularBuffer {
    std::vector<T> _elements;
    size_t _first, _n;
public:
    CircularBuffer(size_t n);
    void push(T v);
    T front() const;
    void pop();
    size_t size() const;
};

template<typename T>
CircularBuffer<T>::CircularBuffer(size_t n)
    : _elements(n), _first(0), _n(0) //?
{
}
```

Gostaria de entender o que é e a utilidade da linha de código que marquei com um comentário e interrogação

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169175/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os atributos de classe `_first` e `_n` estão sendo inicializados com o valor `0`.

O atributo `_elements`, trata-se de um `std::vector` e está sendo construído com tamanho inicial `n`, por meio de um de seus construtores não padrão.

Tudo isso acontece antes da execução do construtor de `CircularBuffer` e conforme a ordem na qual eles foram especificados.