# Sintaxe dentro de uma struct que parece uma função

Tags: c++, struct, sintaxe, construtor

Estava a analisar um código em C++ e me deparei com a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct ligacao {
  int v_;
  int w_;
  int ComEXp; 
  ligacao(int v, int w, int ComEXp1) : v_(v), w_(w), ComEXp(ComEXp1) {} // Minha duvida seria concretamente aqui
};
```

Para que serve a 4º alinha desse trecho?

Comment: Foi util sim Ja aceitei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um método construtor. Não sabe o que é? Tem resposta sobre: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Então é esse código que será executado quando for criar um objeto instanciado partindo dessa estrutura. Péra, que código? É, tem um código aí, ainda que de forma diferente.

A inicialização é feita de forma direta sem precisa atribuir os valores no corpo do método. Isso é garantido que a inicialização seja feita antes do corpo, seja feita *inplace* sem intermediários e que ocorra sempre, sem riscos de alguém apagar ou mudar a semântica inadvertidamente quando mexer no código do corpo. Isso pode ser visto com mais detalhes em [Qual a diferença entre inicializar uma variável nesses construtores? E como colocar um construtor como padrão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250889/101) e [Qual é a diferença entre inicializar um construtor ou fazer atribuição dentro do construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169175/101).

A documentação disso está em https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.